# Is it "excel in" or "excel at" English?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've read another post about *excel at* or *excel in*. But it was too general.

What if the object is a language? When we say "in English" or "in German" it means written or spoken in the mentioned language. But what about "excelling" at/in that language? It feels wrong to say "at", and the same with "in".

Native speakers, please help! Which one sounds or feels natural to you?

> excel **at** English
>   or
>   excel **in** English

Comment: You excel _at_ a skill, but English is a language more than a set skill: You excel _in_ English.

Comment: He excels at speaking English. She excels at playing the piano. To excel AT something. You can't excel at English [that would mean a place!!!], only at English speaking, writing in English. Etc. You excel at [doing something/verb].

Comment: This seems dupey.

Comment: True - search for "excel at" "excel in" for multiple questions of this form.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience as a reader / writer, both read almost interchangeably in many cases. If I have any preference at all, it would be this: you excel *at* a task; you excel *in* a domain, and occasionally a task.

Examples:

- I excel at swimming.
- I excel at peeling garlic cloves.
- I excel in biology.
- I excel in intellectual property law.

Bad examples:

- "I excel at biology" looks slightly-to-moderately odd, as if "biology" were a task. We don't biologize anything. :-)
- "I excel in swimming" looks slightly odd, *depending* on whether I intend "swimming" to refer to the task ("at" would be more appropriate) or the general subject ("in" would be more appropriate).
- "I excel in peeling garlic cloves" looks definitely odd, since peeling garlic cloves is virtually always intended to denote a task.